# ¿Cómo contabilizar únicamente los días laborales entre dos fechas en MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada **vacaciones**, donde se muestra el número de empleado junto con la fecha inicial y final de sus vacaciones:

| no_empleado | inicial | final |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2020-12-24 | 2021-01-04 |

Lo que busco es visualizar la cantidad de días de vacaciones que tuvo cada empleado, pero separándolos por número de empleado, mes, año y cantidad de días; sin tomar en cuenta los días inhábiles (sábados, domingos y días festivos).

Tengo la siguiente *query* con la que he trabajado, la cuál logra omitir los días sábado y domingo de la contabilización:

```sql
SELECT no_empleado, 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.Fecha) AS ano, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.Fecha) AS mes, 
       SUM(WEEKDAY(`Fecha`) < 5) as Dias 
FROM (SELECT v.no_empleado, 
             DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) AS Fecha 
FROM vacaciones v CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_100 s 
WHERE DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.final 
ORDER BY v.no_empleado, v.inicial, s.seq ) t 
GROUP BY no_empleado, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Fecha);
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo podría además de omitir los fines de semana, también omitir los días festivos? Supongo que debería establecer otra tabla donde se almacenen las fechas de dichos días pero, ¿cómo se podría adaptar mi *query* para realizar la comparativa?

Si tenemos en cuenta que el empleado **1001** tomó sus vacaciones desde el **2020-12-24** hasta el **2021-01-04** y tomamos Navidad y Año Nuevo como días festivos, debería obtenerse el siguiente resultado:

| no_empleado | mes | año | dias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 12 | 2020 | 5 |
| 1001 | 1 | 2021 | 1 |

Comment: necesitas una tabla de dias feriados.. y la unis con un not in...

Comment: ¿Cómo se aplicaría ```NOT IN``` en la sentencia?

Comment: depende de la tabla de dias feriados que construyas.. pero en google dice como se usa un not in ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establecí una tabla llamada **festivos**, que contiene las fechas de los días festivos con la siguiente estructura:

| id | fecha | descripcion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020-12-25 | Navidad |
| 02 | 2021-01-01 | Año Nuevo |

Y con la tabla anterior establecida dentro del problema previamente descrita, adapté la *query* inicialmente propuesta en la pregunta para resolver la problemática:

```sql
SELECT no_empleado, 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.Date) AS ano, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.Date) AS mes, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.fecha IS NULL THEN WEEKDAY(`Date`) < 5 END) AS dias 
FROM (SELECT v.no_empleado, DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) AS Date 
      FROM vacaciones v CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_100 s 
      WHERE DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.final 
      ORDER BY v.no_empleado, v.inicial, s.seq ) t 
LEFT JOIN festivos f ON t.Date=f.fecha 
GROUP BY no_empleado, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Date);
```

Con la *query* anterior, se obtiene el siguiente resultado:

| no_empleado | mes | ano | dias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 12 | 2020 | 5 |
| 1001 | 1 | 2021 | 1 |

El único inconveniente que encuentro, es que se tienen que establecer las fechas de los días festivos de cada año, por lo que por decir algo, en el caso de Navidad, se tiene que establecer dicha fecha por cada año en lugar de establecer simplemente el día y el mes. Aunque a la vez encuentro positivo llevar control en cuanto a las festividades de cada año, ya que pueden existir variaciones de vez en vez.

Comment: Puedes colocar aqui tus tablas http://sqlfiddle.com/ para ayudarte mejor y con ejemplos

Comment: @JosueVargas, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=964b0180e3672b91376a568f948349db

Comment: Usualmente pasa eso.. y se hace asi (usualmente) porque muchos dias feriados suelen cambiar de dia... aunque algunos son siempre fijos...